# How to add a css class on resizing the column in extjs 6 grid

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have a Buffered grid.For some of the columns the column data is like "lisa...@com"(which is static) if the column data's text width is more than the column's width.

And on resizing the column, I want the column's data to be expanded i mean as text-overflow:normal,if the column data's (text width>=column's width).
How can I achieve that?
Please check the sample fiddler
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2dmt

Note: Ignore "homer@simpsons.com" below the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the grid, add a columnresize listener that refreshes the grid view like this:

```
listeners: {
    columnresize: function(headerContainer) {
        headerContainer.grid.getView().refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Tq for d response.
I will check and will let u know

Comment: Your answer is perfect.. Thank you very much @Alexander